# SQL Join 2 tables with almost same field

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to join two tables in SQL. There are no common fields. But the one table have a field with the value `krin1001` and I need it to be joined with the row in the other table where the value is `1001`.

The idea behind the joining is i have multiple customers, but in the one table there customer id is 'krin1001' 'krin1002' and so on, in this table is how much they have sold. In the other table there customer is is '1001' '1002' and so on, and in this table is there name and adress and so on. So it will always be the first 4 charakters i need to strip from the field before matching and joining. It might not always be 'krin' i need it to work with 'khjo1001' also, and it still needs to join on the '1001' value from the other table.

Is that possible?

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Add table definitions, sample table data and expected result.

Comment: There are a few things that could help someone to give you a solution. What is the logic behind "krin1001" = "1001" ? Is the "krin" before the first a constant or, at least, its length? Are there only 4 characters that are in common (in this case the LAST four, like "1001")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use substring:

```
ON SUBSTRING(TableA.Field, 5, 4) = TableB.Field
```

Or Right:

```
ON RIGHT(TableA.Field, 4) = TableB.Field
```

Comment: Okay. So what this is doing is telling is to start looking for a match from the 5th charakter in the field in tableB, and only look for the next 4 charakters? Right?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use `CHARINDEX` function for join operation. If value from `table1` contains value from `table2` row will be included in result set.

```
;WITH table1 AS(
    SELECT 'krin1001' AS val
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'xxx'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'xyz123'
),
table2 AS(
    SELECT '1001' AS val
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '12345'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '123'
)

SELECT * FROM table1 AS t
  JOIN table2 AS T2 ON CHARINDEX(T2.val, T.val) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it as:

```
SELECT
*
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN table t2 ON RIGHT(t1.col1, 4) = t2.col1;
```